# Indirectly breaking the speed of light through inflationary phase

Tags: special-relativity, cosmology, space-expansion, faster-than-light, cosmological-inflation

How do you define velocity? Rate of change of "space" between two objects-and that will give relative velocity between them. Now in inflationary phase the universe expanded faster than light i.e. the space/gap between any two objects expanded faster than light and that's how relative velocity is defined. So it means object "indirectly" broke the speed limit but how?
I know I might be wrong but where?

Only two assumptions,

1. In inflationary phase objects like electron pairs exist
2. Velocity is the rate of change of space with respect to time and it's indistinguishable whether something moving through space or space between them is expanding/contracting.

Answer (score 1):

> So it means object "indirectly" broke the speed limit but how?

The actual limit is that nothing with mass can move faster than light. In an inertial frame light travels at c, but not necessarily in a non inertial frame. The cosmological reference frame is non-inertial, so the limit to speeds less than c does not apply. The actual limit, expressed in a way that works in all reference frames, is that the worldlines of massive objects are always timelike.

During inflation (and now too) objects moved faster than c, but not faster than light. The actual limit was not broken. All massive objects had timelike worldlines during inflation.

Answer (score 1):

The distance between objects increased because the whole universe expanded, not because the objects moved away from each other. There is no constraint on the speed at which the universe can expand.

In Relativity, nothing can move faster than lightspeed, but Relativity is a law of local physics. It does not apply to the universe as a whole. The speed of light is only a constraint for objects that exist within space-time, not for space-time itself.

Due to the universe's expansion, any galaxy with a redshift of 4 or greater is *currently* moving away from us at more than lightspeed.

Answer (score 0):

I would add that this phenomenon is still presented. Because of space expansion, a distant galaxy is going way from us with velocity given by Hubble law: $v = H r$, where $H$ is Hubbe constant and $r$ is a distance of a galaxy. As you can see this is a simple linear relation and no restriction on velocity is incorporated like in formulas of special relavity.

This means that a galaxy can go away from us faster than light. Such galaxy is not observable as the light emitted by it cannot overtake expansion of the space. We say that the galaxy is behind the space events horizont. However, the galaxy itself does not move faster than light locally, it is the space itself what is "expanding and moving".